# How to insert video permanently inside netbeans app/project

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.media.*;
import java.net.*;
/**
 *
 * @author User
 */

public class NewClass extends JFrame {
static Player mp4Player = null;
public NewClass() {
super("Demo JMF");
play();
Component panelControl = mp4Player.getControlPanelComponent();
Component visualComponent = mp4Player.getVisualComponent();
this.getContentPane().add(panelControl, BorderLayout.WEST);
this.getContentPane().add(visualComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
stop();
System.exit(0);
}});
this.pack();
this.setSize(new Dimension(1080, 720));
this.setVisible(true);}
public static void main(String[] args) {
NewClass NewClass = new NewClass();
}
void play() {
try {URL url = new URL("file",null,"\"C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\_Getintopc.com_Autodesk_Maya_2022.mp4\"");
mp4Player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
mp4Player.start();
}
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("unable to play :" + e);
}}
void stop() {
mp4Player.stop();
mp4Player.close();}}
```

so this is the code
after i run it the output says:
unable to play :java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
i already use jmf pluggin in the project libraries

if you guys have any idea also appreciated to share with me on how to insert video since im making an app where one of the option will open my video on it

Answer (score 0):

You should put your video to your resource folder on your project, then load the video from your resource folder on your project. You can read the tutorial [here](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans) or [here](https://www.javaquery.com/2015/10/how-to-create-resource-folder-in.html).